# Showing linearly independent of $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The function y(t) is a solution of the homogeneous equation $y''+4y=0$ if and only if $x(t)= \begin{pmatrix}x_1(t) \\ x_2(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} y(t) \\ y'(t) \end{pmatrix}$ is a solution of $x'=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -4 & 0 \end{pmatrix} x$

$x_1(t)= (\sin 2t, 2\cos 2t )^T$ and $x_2(t)= (\cos 2t, -2\sin2t )^T$. Show that $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ are linearly independent.

$x_1(t)'=(2 \cos 2t,-4 \sin 2t)^T$ and $x_2(t)'=(-2\sin 2t, -4 \cos 2t)^T$.

$\begin{vmatrix} x_1(t) & x_2(t) \\ x_1(t)' & x_2(t)' \end{vmatrix} \neq 0$. Checked. Is that brief sketch enough?

Comment: did you try computing the Wronskian?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner just a sketch, so it does work here right?

Comment: Your 2nd ode is missing an $x$, I believe. Otherwise the solutions will be unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Wronskian is $\begin{vmatrix}\sin2t&&\cos2t\\2\cos 2t&&-2\sin2t\end{vmatrix}=-2(\sin^22t+\cos^22t)=-2\ne0,$

so they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the theory of the Wronskian. Sure. Or, just consider
$$ c_1(\sin 2t, 2\cos 2t)+c_2(\cos 2t, -2 \sin2t) = 0 $$
for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove the above equation forces $c_1=0$ and $c_2=0$.

Hint: try plugging in $t=0$ and looking at the components of the vector equation separately.